# Try to delete some duplicated white spaces with ' 'join(x.split()) but failed

Tags: python, string, pandas

My first question here for a very basic question in python but I've stuck for two days long.

I've tried to eliminate some duplicated white spacing with all the methods I can find on internet but I don't understand the reason that the length of string remains the same. Shouldn't they be decrease?
Here below is my code:

```
print(df['NAME'][0])
len(df['NAME'][0])

print(' '.join(df['NAME'][0].split()))
len(df['NAME'][0])
```

The result of the code can be found in the photo below. Thanks for your help in advance.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzXkW.png)

Comment: You're not changing the original element in your data frame, therefore printing the length of the df element will always result in 18. Try changing the `print` in your second cell to a `len` and you'll see the length has in fact decreased. If you want to change the df element, assign the value back to the df

Comment: appreciate your reply. I realized that I am not familiar with the basic concept of code yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting the value and then again joining them with spaces. This will create the original value again.

Also yopu are not assigning the value after split to the df. So checking the length of df value will return same.

Try this :

```
print(df['NAME'][0])
len(df['NAME'][0])

df['Name'][0] = ''.join(df['NAME'][0].split())

print(df['NAME'][0])
len(df['NAME'][0])
```

Comment: Thank you. You indeed solved my problem. I was working to apply this code to the whole column.